# How can I read a list of filenames from a file in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to write a bash script that will process a list of files whose names are stored one per line in an input file, something the likes of

```
find . -type f -mtime +15 > /tmp/filelist.txt
for F in $(cat /tmp/filelist.txt) ; do
  ...
done;
```

My problem is that filenames in filelist.txt may contain spaces, so the snipped above will expand the line

```
my text file.txt
```

to three different filenames, `my`, `text` and `file.txt`. How can I fix that?

Comment: You know, directory entries can also contain newlines, as well as spaces and other wacky characters.  The only things a directory entry (file name) can't have are the "/" and the "" characters. (slash and null).

Comment: Yep, but the files I'm working on are created by windows users on my LAN accessing a samba share, so there's a limit to filename weirdness

Comment: You can also create an array from a file cf.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash
See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `read`:

```
while read F  ; do
        echo $F
done </tmp/filelist.txt
```

Alternatively use IFS to change how the shell separates your list:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="
"
for F in $(cat /tmp/filelist.txt) ; do
  echo $F
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Alternatively (as suggested by @tangens), convert the body of your loop into a separate script, then use `find`'s -exec option to run if for each file found directly.

Comment: Although I voted it up, I found this script fail on paths that contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Note that a newline character (line break) is expected even at the end of last line, which on Linux systems requires pressing an extra Enter to create and an empty line at the end of the file to avoid an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without a temporary file using process substitution:

```
while read F
do
  ...
done < <(find . -type f -mtime +15)
```

Comment: Neat! Didn't know about process substitution.

Comment: Note that the process substitution feature is a bash extension, and is not even available with bash in sh-compatibility mode.  You must start your script with `#!/bin/bash` for it to work.  BTW, I also recommend using `while IFS="" read -r F` to avoid possible problems with whitespace at the beginning or end of filenames, and backslashes at the end (although if the files are coming from Windows, backslashes are probably not possible).

Answer (score 6):

use while read

```
cat $FILE | while read line
do
echo $line
done
```

You can do redirect instead of cat with a pipe

Comment: If you've only got one file, then a shell redirect avoids spawning a `cat` process.

Comment: That worked for me, but first 'echo' call should be 'cat', I think. Anyway that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `-exec` parameter of `find` and use the file names directly:

```
find . -type f -mtime +15 -exec <your command here> {} \;
```

The `{}` is a placeholder for the file name.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not running a single command and I would end up trying all types of weird combinations to find the right way to quote and escape the stuff after -exec

Answer (score 3):

pipe your find command straight to while read loop

```
find . -type f -mtime +15 | while read -r line
do
   printf "do something with $line\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a bash expert by any means ( I usually write my script in ruby or python to be cross-platform), but I would use a regex expration to escape spaces in each line before you process it.

For Bash Regex:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1006996

In a similar situation in Ruby ( processing a csv file, and cleaning up each line before using it):

```
File.foreach(csv_file_name) do |line| 
    clean_line = line.gsub(/( )/, '\ ') 
    #this finds the space in your file name and escapes it    
    #do more stuff here
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can skip the temporary file entirely and just directly iterate over the results of find, i.e.:

```
for F in $(find . -type f -mtime +15) ; do
  ...
done;
```

No guarantees that my syntax is correct but I'm pretty sure the concept works.

Edit: If you really do have to process the file with a list of filenames and can't simply combine the commands as I did above, then you can change the value of the `IFS` variable--it stands for Internal Field Separator--to change how bash determines fields.  By default it is set to whitespace, so a newline, space, or tab will begin a new field.  If you set it to contain only a newline, then you can iterate over the file just as you did before.

Comment: I think the shell will still do separation on white-space?