# Load List From Text File To Bash Script

Tags: bash, list, text-files

I've a `.txt` file which contains

```
abc.com
google.com
....
....
yahoo.com
```

And I'm interested in loading it to a bash script as a list (i.e. `Domain_List=( "abc.com" "google.com" .... "yahoo.com")` ). Is it possible to do?

Additional information, once the list is obtained it is used in a `for` loop and `if` statements.

```
 for i in "${Domain_list[@]}
 do
     if grep -q "${Domain_list[counter]}" domains.log
   ....
   ....
     fi
 ....
     let counter=counter+1
 done
```

Thank you,

Update:
I've changed the format to Domain_list=( "google.com .... "yahoo.com" ), and using `source Doamin.txt` allows me to use `Domain_list` as a list in the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
source domain.txt
for i in "${domain_list[@]}"
do
   echo "${domain_list[counter]}"
   let counter=counter+1
done
echo "$counter"
```

Comment: Your question has been answered before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688999/how-can-i-read-a-list-of-filenames-from-a-file-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the source command, and it works fine.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 counter=0
 source domain.txt
 for i in "${domain_list[@]}"
 do
    echo "${domain_list[counter]}"
    let counter=counter+1
 done
 echo "$counter"
```

Comment: This one is simple and can be used for other type of files e.g. .properties file.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose, your datafile name is web.txt. Using command substitution (backtics) and cat, the array can be built. Pl. see the following code,

```
myarray=(`cat web.txt`)
noofelements=${#myarray[*]}
#now traverse the array
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $noofelements ]
do
    echo " Element $counter is  ${myarray[$counter]}"
    counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))

done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Domain_list=()
while read addr
do
    Domain_list+=($addr)
done < addresses.txt
```

That should store each line of the text file into the array.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but a quick question, is there a difference (as how the script stores it) between the way I've implemented it and your way?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a counter if we're sourcing the list from a file. You can simply iterate through the list and echo the value.

```
#!/bin/bash

source domain.txt
for i in ${domain_list[@]}
do
   echo $i
done
```