# Creating an array from a text file in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, scripting, variable-assignment

A script takes a URL, parses it for the required fields, and redirects its output to be saved in a file, *file.txt*. The output is saved on a new line each time a field has been found.

#### file.txt

```
A Cat
A Dog
A Mouse 
etc...
```

I want to take `file.txt` and create an array from it in a new script, where every line gets to be its own string variable in the array. So far I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=file.txt
declare -a myArray
myArray=(`cat "$filename"`)

for (( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++))
do
  echo "Element [$i]: ${myArray[$i]}"
done
```

When I run this script, whitespace results in words getting split and instead of getting

#### Desired output

```
Element [0]: A Cat 
Element [1]: A Dog 
etc...
```

I end up getting this:

#### Actual output

```
Element [0]: A 
Element [1]: Cat 
Element [2]: A
Element [3]: Dog 
etc...
```

How can I adjust the loop below such that the entire string on each line will correspond one-to-one with each variable in the array?

Comment: This is what [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is all about. Also [this section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005?highlight=%28readarray%29#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) of the array topic in [Bash FAQ 005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Comment: I would link this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/bash-read-lines-in-file-into-an-array, but the accepted answer there is awful.

Comment: Etan, thank you so much for such a fast and accurate reply! I had tried to search my question in the forums, but did not think to look for the FAQ on stackoverflow. 
The mapfile command addressed my needs exactly! Thanks again :)

Answer in [section 2.1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005?highlight=%28readarray%29#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream).

Comment: (Set up the link in the opposite direction, since we have a better accepted answer here than we have there).

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Use the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) command:

```
mapfile -t myArray < file.txt
```

The error is using `for` -- the idiomatic way to loop over *lines* of a file is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo ">>$line<<"; done < file.txt
```

See [BashFAQ/005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) for more details.

Comment: Since this is being promoted as the canonical q&a, you could also include what is mentioned in the link: `while IFS= read -r; do lines+=("$REPLY"); done <file`.

Comment: mapfile does not exist in bash versions prior to 4.x

Comment: Bash 4 is about 5 years old now. Upgrade.

Comment: Despite bash 4 being released in 2009, @ericslaw's comment remains relevant because many machines still ship with bash 3.x (and will not upgrade, so long as bash is released under GPLv3). If you're interested in portability, it's an important thing to note

Comment: Sure, an OS may ship with older bash, but individuals can upgrade their own installations, or install bash 4 separately (with homebrew or the like).

Comment: macos mojave bash reports as 3.2.57 (wow really apple?).
I suspect work wont let me touch too many things on the laptop though :(

Comment: You should be able to use whatever tools you need to do your job.

Comment: the issue isn't that a developer can't install an upgraded version, it's that a developer should be aware that a script using `mapfile` will not run as expected on many machines without additional steps. @ericslaw macs will continue to ship with bash 3.2.57 for the foreseeable future. More recent versions use a license that would require apple to share or allow things they don't want to share or allow.

Comment: @glennjackman Some of us work in corporate environments with strongly worded policies against anything GPL'ed.

Answer (score 46):

`mapfile` and `readarray` (which are synonymous) are available in Bash version 4 and above.  If you have an older version of Bash, you can use a loop to read the file into an array:

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  arr+=("$line")
done < file
```

In case the file has an incomplete (missing newline) last line, you could use this alternative:

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -r line || [[ "$line" ]]; do
  arr+=("$line")
done < file
```

---

Related:

- [Need alternative to readarray/mapfile for script on older version of Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475261/need-alternative-to-readarray-mapfile-for-script-on-older-system)

Comment: I find it that I have to put parentheses around `IFS= read -r line || [[ "$line" ]]` for it to work. Otherwise, it works great!

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: isn't it that the semicolon that was missing before `do`?

Answer (score 11):

You can do this too:

```
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(<file))
IFS="$oldIFS"
echo "${arr[1]}" # It will print `A Dog`.
```

Note:

Filename expansion still occurs. For example, if there's a line with a literal `*` it will expand to all the files in current folder. So use it only if your file is free of this kind of scenario.

Comment: Is there any way to set `IFS` only temporarily (so that it recovers its original value after this command), while still persisting the assignment to `arr`?

Comment: Note that filename expansion still occurs; e.g. `IFS=$'\n' arr=($(echo 'a  1'; echo '*'; echo 'b 2')); printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: @Hugues : yap, filename expansion still occurs. I will add that bit of info..thnks..

Comment: Sorry, I disagree.   `IFS=... command` does not change `IFS` in the current shell.  However, `IFS=...  other_variable=...` (without any command) does change both `IFS` and `other_variable` in the current shell.

Comment: @Hugues : You are right again, sorry about that... Fixed it with save-and-reset way.

Comment: Thanks!  This works; it's unfortunate that there is no simpler way as I like the `arr=` notation (compared to `mapfile`/`readarray`).

Answer (score 11):

### Use mapfile or read -a

Always check your code using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). It will often give you the correct answer. In this case [SC2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207) covers reading a file that either has space separated or newline separated values into an array.

#### Don't do this

```
array=( $(mycommand) )
```

#### Files with values separated by newlines

```
mapfile -t array < <(mycommand)
```

#### Files with values separated by spaces

```
IFS=" " read -r -a array <<< "$(mycommand)"
```

The shellcheck page will give you the rationale why this is considered best practice.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply read each line from the file and assign it to an array.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read line 
do
        arr[$i]="$line"
        i=$((i+1))
done < file.txt
```

Comment: How do you access the array?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988704/7381355) says to use

```
mapfile -t myArray < file.txt
```

I made a [shim](https://github.com/dosentmatter/bash-mapfile-shim) for `mapfile` if you want to use `mapfile` on bash < 4.x for whatever reason. It uses the existing `mapfile` command if you are on bash >= 4.x

Currently, only options `-d` and `-t` work. But that should be enough for that command above. I've only tested on macOS. On macOS Sierra 10.12.6, the system bash is `3.2.57(1)-release`. So the shim can come in handy. You can also just update your bash with homebrew, build bash yourself, etc.

It uses [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540298/bash-passing-arguments-by-reference) to set variables up one call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure set the Internal File Separator (IFS)
variable to  $'\n' so that it does not put each word
into a new array entry.

```
#!/bin/bash

# move all 2020 - 2022 movies to /backup/movies
# put list into file 1 line per dir

# dirs are  "movie name (year)/"
ls | egrep 202[0-2]  > 2020_movies.txt

OLDIFS=${IFS}
  
IFS=$'\n'    #fix separator

declare -a MOVIES  # array for dir names

MOVIES=( $( cat "${1}" ) )  // load into array 

for M in ${MOVIES[@]} ; do
        echo "[${M}]"
        if [ -d "${M}" ] ; then  # if dir name

                mv -v "$M" /backup/movies/
        fi

done

IFS=${OLDIFS}  # restore standard separators
               # not essential as IFS reverts when script ends

#END
```