# split command output into array of lines

Tags: bash

Here's my bash function to get a command's output as parameter and then return an array of output lines.

```
function get_lines { 
    while read -r line; do 
        echo $line
    done <<< $1
}

SESSIONS=`loginctl list-sessions`
get_lines "$SESSIONS"
```

Actual output of `loginctl list-sessions` is:

```
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT            
        c2       1000 asif             seat0           
        c7       1002 sadia            seat0
```

But the while loop only runs once printing all output in a single line. How can I get an array of lines and return it?

Answer (score 3):

You could use readarray and avoid the get_lines function:

```
readarray SESSIONS < <(loginctl --no-legend list-sessions)
```

this create the array `SESSIONS` with each line of the output of the command mapped to an element of the array.

Comment: ++, but you should add `-t` so as not to capture the trailing `\n` along with each input line; `readarray` requires Bash 4.x.

Comment: Looks great. I don't get `< <(` part. What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>The value of this answer is in explaining the problem with the OP's code.

 - The other answers show the use of **Bash v4+** builtin `mapfile` (or its effective alias, `readarray`) for directly reading input line by line into the elements of an array, without the need for a custom shell function.

 - In **Bash v3.x**, you can use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a lines < <(...),`, but note that empty lines will be ignored.</sup>

---

Your primary problem is that *unquoted* (non-double-quoted) use of `$1` makes the shell apply [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) to its contents, which effectively normalizes all runs of whitespace - including newlines - to a single space each, resulting in a *single* input line to the `while` loop.

Secondarily, using `$input` unquoted applies this word-splitting again on output with `echo`.

Finally, by using `read` without setting [`$IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting), the internal field separator, to the empty string - via `IFS= read -r line` - leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed from each input line.

That said, you can simplify your function to read directly from stdin rather than taking arguments:

```
function get_lines { 
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    done
}
```

which you can then invoke as follows, using a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
get_lines < <(loginctl list-sessions)
```

Using a pipeline would work too, but `get_lines` would then run in a *subshell*, which means that it can't set variables visible to the *current* shell:

```
loginctl list-sessions | get_lines
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a way in `bash` v4+:

```
SESSIONS=`loginctl list-sessions`
mapfile -t myArray <<< "$SESSIONS"
```

ref:

[Creating an array from a text file in BASH with mapfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988704/1563960)

Comment: ++; worth noting that `mapfile` (and its effective alias, `readarray`) require Bash 4.x.