# Bash - Only go next index when new line occurs, instead of white space?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I'm parsing a JSON response with a tool called jq.
The output from jq will give me a list of full names in my command line.

I have the variable *getNames* which contains JSON, for example:

```
{
    "count": 49,
    "user": [{
        "username": "jamesbrown",
        "name": "James Brown",
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "username": "matthewthompson",
        "name": "Matthew Thompson",
        "id": 2
    }]
}
```

I pass this through JQ to filter the json using the following command:

```
echo $getNames | jq -r .user[].name
```

Which gives me a list like this:

```
James Brown   
Matthew Thompson
```

I want to put each one of these entries into a bash array, so I enter the following commands:

```
declare -a myArray    
myArray=( `echo $getNames | jq -r .user[].name` )
```

However, when I try to print the array using:

```
printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"
```

I get the following:

```
James
Brown
Matthew
Thompson
```

How do I ensure that a new index is created after a new line and not a space? Why are the names being separated?

Thanks.

Comment: you should provide a way to get `getNames` so we can test. Also, most probably the problem lies in lack of quotes: say `echo "$getNames"` to preserve format.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the JSON as it is confidential. I tried placing quotes around $getNames however this did not fix my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple script in `bash` to feed each line of the output into the array `myArray`.

```
#!/bin/bash

myArray=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line ]] || break  # break if line is empty
    myArray+=("$line")
done < <(jq -r .user[].name <<< "$getNames")

# To print the array
printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"
```

Comment: Hi - when putting a variable into this script such as:

done < <($variable)

I get 

variable value: command not found 

errors. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Xenidious: You need to use a different operator `<<<` for that, refer this page http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html#HERESTRINGSREF

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `mapfile` command to read multiple lines into an array like this:

```
mapfile -t myArray < <(jq -r .user[].name <<< "$getNames")
```

Comment: Nice! From what I read in the links to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988704/1983854), it needs Bash 4.

Comment: Yes that's true `mapfile` in available in BASH 4+ only