# How to read the last two lines of a file into an array of length two in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, tail

I am trying to read the last two lines of a file in an array of length two.

Consider the file `a.txt`

```
bar
second line
hello world
foo bar fubar
```

I tried

```
lines=($(tail -n 2 a.txt))
```

but this results in an array of length 5, each containing a single word. I read the post [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash) but fail to go from there to reading only the last two lines. Please note that efficiency (execution time) matters for my needs.

I am on Mac OS X using Terminal 2.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mapfile` command in `bash` for this. Just `tail` the last 2 lines and store them in the array

```
mapfile -t myArray < <(tail -n 2 file)
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[0]}"
hello world
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[1]}"
foo bar fubar
```

See more on the [`mapfile` builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) and the options available.

---

If `mapfile` is not available because of some older versions of `bash`, you can just the `read` command with process-substitution as below

```
myArray=()
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    myArray+=("$line") 
done < <(tail -n 2 file)
```

and print the array element as before

```
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[0]}"
```

Comment: Hum.... I am on MAC using Terminal version 2.6.1 (info edited on post) (`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`). I don't have the mapfile builtin unfortunately. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Remi.b: Check my update which should work on older versions also!

Comment: @Remi.b: then use two `read` statements: `lines=(); { IFS= read -r 'lines[0]'; IFS= read -r 'lines[1]'; } < <(tail -n2 file)`.

Answer (score 0):

try following once and let me know if this helps you.

```
array[0]=$(tail -2 Input_file | head -1)
array[1]=$(tail -1 Input_file)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
echo ${array[0]}
hello world
echo ${array[1]}
foo bar fubar
```

Comment: `tail -2 .. | head -1` is a bit of an anti-pattern! when you can do it more directly. Also I see no reason you want to store the values from index `1` when you can do it from `0`

Comment: Thanks Inian, actually why I have done tail -2 | head -1 tried to do in OP's style itself. Yes, we could do from array[0] and array[1], I simply given examples, let me fix it now. Thank you sir for your guidance here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
# read file in an array
mapfile -t ary < file

# slice last 2 elements
printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]: -2}"
```

---

If you don't have `mapfile` then use this `while` loop to populate your array:

```
ary=()
while read -r; do
   ary+=("$REPLY")
done < file

printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]: -2}"
```

**Output:**

```
hello world
foo bar fubar
```