# Using array from an output file in bash shell

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

am in a need of using an array to set the variable value for further manipulations from the output file.

scenario:

```
> 1. fetch the list from database 
> 2. trim the column using sed to a file named x.txt (got specific value as that is required)
> 3. this file x.txt has the below output as
10000 
20000 
30000
> 4. I need to set a variable and assign the above values to it.  
A=10000 
B=20000 
C=30000
> 5. I can invoke this variable A,B,C for further manipulations.
```

Please let me know how to define an array assigning to its variable from the output file.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to write a shell script? For which shell? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988704/10622916

Comment: It looks like you want 3 variables named A, B, and C.  Where is the array?

Comment: To be specific the x.txt file contains below values 

10.20.30.40
20.30.40.50

I want the above output to be assigned to a variable say SET[i]
SET1=10.20.30.40
SET2=20.30.40.50

So I can invoke SET1 and SET2 for further manipulations.

Comment: @Bodo - thanks for the link it works using mapfile -t.

Comment: I can copy this to an answer to make the question more useful for others. I suggest to add a `bash` tag.

Comment: added bash tag.

Comment: mapfile -t arr < file.txt

for((i=0;i<3;I++))
do
    echo "SET$i=${arr[$i]}"
done
this worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash` (starting from version 4.x) and  you can use the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) command:

```
mapfile -t myArray < file.txt
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988704/10622916

or another answer for older bash versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46225812/10622916

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big proponent of using arrays in bash (if your code is complex enough to need an array, it's complex enough to need a more robust language), but you can do:

```
$ unset a
$ unset i
$ declare -a a
$ while read line; do a[$((i++))]="$line"; done < x.txt
```

(I've left the interactive prompt in place.  Remove the leading `$` 
if you want to put this in a script.)