# how to make separate temp directories for each processes in a batch job

Tags: bash, command-line, supercomputers

I have just started learning bioinformatics in my lab and I am a complete newbie. 
I am using a genome annotation tool called Kofamscan from NCBI and I am getting an error that could be due to the fact results of multiple processes are being stored in the same temp directory and the files are collapsing.
So I want to create separate temp directories per process (temp1 for process1, temp2 for process2,...etc) but I don't know how to write the code that enables it.

```sh
files=(`cat kofam_files`) #input files 

TASK_ID = `expr ${SGE_TASK_ID} -1`

~/kofamscan/bin/exec_annotation -o marine_kofam.txt --tmp-dir **** ${files[$TASK_ID]}
```

I probably need to write something in the `****` section of the above code but I don't know how to write them.

Thank you in advance.

Ryohei

Comment: This isn't batch, it's bash.

Comment: Can you paste the full code of your script - exec_annotation ?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why [`mktemp` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html) exists :)

The following snippet the minimal changes you would have to make to yours:

```sh
files=(`cat kofam_files`) #input files 

TASK_ID=`expr ${SGE_TASK_ID} -1`

~/kofamscan/bin/exec_annotation -o marine_kofam.txt --tmp-dir `mktemp -d` ${files[$TASK_ID]}
```

Note that the temp directory would be created in `/tmp` though. You could use the flags for `mktemp` to  create temp subdirectories in the current directory.

**EDIT :** Folowing the best practices for `bash`, one would also,

1. Use newer the `mapfile` or `readarray` commands (in `bash` 4+) instead of using `cat` to [create arrays in `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash)
2. Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` since [they support nesting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)
3. Use `$((...))` instead of the archaic `expr` syntax (see [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286209/using-expr))

The final snippet would then look like:

```sh
readarray -t files < kofam_files #input files 

TASK_ID=$((SGE_TASK_ID - 1))

~/kofamscan/bin/exec_annotation -o marine_kofam.txt --tmp-dir $(mktemp -d) ${files[$TASK_ID]}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was busy with something else that I had to get rid of straight away... Thanks for your advice, I will try it out!