# printf within for is not iterating in bash

Tags: bash

Team,
am trying to print all elements for array with some string in bash over for loop but its just print elements not the string along.

```
if [ "$FILTER" = "ALL" ]; then
  vm_ip_all=$(./command_to_get_ips)
  printf "got all IPs \\n %s" "$vm_ip_all"
else
  echo "could not get all IPs"
fi

#for vm_ip in "${vm_ip_all[@]}"; do <<same result as below
for vm_ip in "${vm_ip_all}"; do
  printf "\\n BEGIN FOR \\n"
  echo "iterating for $vm_ip"
echo "END FOR"
done
```

Actual output:

```
got all IPs
 10.0.1.6
10.0.1.10
BEGIN FOR
iterating for 10.0.1.6
10.0.1.10
```

Expected output:

```
got all IPs
 10.0.1.6
10.0.1.10
BEGIN FOR
iterating for 10.0.1.6
iterating for 10.0.1.10
END FOR
```

vm_ip_all

````
10.0.1.6 10.0.1.10 ```
````

Comment: You are populating your `vm_ip_all` array wrong. See methods explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586

Comment: hmm still can't figure out. I am getting all elements of ```vm_ip_all`` but not able to repeat the text `iterating for`

Comment: Can you update your question with your new `vm_ip_all` array populating code?

Comment: okay. i pasted how my vm_ip_all looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it

```
vm_ip_all=$(./command_to_get_ips)
for vm_ip in $vm_ip_all; do
  echo "iterating for $vm_ip"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To print an array `printf` doesn't even need a loop.  Try something like:

```
printf '\n BEGIN FOR \n'
printf 'iterating for %s\n' "${vm_ip_all[@]}"
printf 'END FOR\n'
```

Comment: or, when it is not an array, use `printf "iterating for %s\n" ${vm_ip_all}` to avoid a loop.

Comment: @WalterA, True, but irrelevant because the OP was *"trying to print all elements for array"* and `$vm_ip_all` *is* an array.