# How to append string into text file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

**data.txt**

```
height= 6'1" age= shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
height= 6'5" age= shoe-size=9.0 sex= M
height= 5'11" age= shoe-size=8.5 sex= F
height= 5'9" age= shoe-size=11.5 sex= M
height= 4'11" age= shoe-size=7.5 sex= F
height= 6'4" age= shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
```

**age.txt**

```
21
23
22
19
34
27
```

How do I grab the information from the `age.txt` and place it into `data.txt`, putting each number following the other into the age portion of `data.txt`?

Is there a way to do a for loop for the number of lines in my file and then look for 'age' and every time I see age, replace it with the number in age.txt

**Expected output**

```
height= 6'1" age=21 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
height= 6'5" age=23 shoe-size=9.0 sex= M
height= 5'11" age=22 shoe-size=8.5 sex= F
height= 5'9" age=19 shoe-size=11.5 sex= M
height= 4'11" age=34 shoe-size=7.5 sex= F
height= 6'4" age=27 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
```

Answer (score 3):

Using bash4 index arrays.

```
mapfile -t data < data.txt
mapfile -t age <age.txt

for i in "${!data[@]}"; do echo "${data[$i]//age=/age="${age[$i]}"}"; done
```

Output is this.

```
height= 6'1" age=21 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
height= 6'5" age=23 shoe-size=9.0 sex= M
height= 5'11" age=22 shoe-size=8.5 sex= F
height= 5'9" age=19 shoe-size=11.5 sex= M
height= 4'11" age=34 shoe-size=7.5 sex= F
height= 6'4" age=27 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
```

`mapfile` aka `readarray` is a bash4+ feature.

The `${!data[@]}` means you're looking for the index of an array and `${data[@]}` is the array.

Or using `while loop` and  `read` `read`, so basically it is just reading the two files inside a while loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line_in_data <&3
  read -r line_in_age; do
  printf '%s\n' "${line_in_data//age=/age=$line_in_age}"
done 3<data.txt <age.txt
```

Should print the same output.

```
height= 6'1" age=21 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
height= 6'5" age=23 shoe-size=9.0 sex= M
height= 5'11" age=22 shoe-size=8.5 sex= F
height= 5'9" age=19 shoe-size=11.5 sex= M
height= 4'11" age=34 shoe-size=7.5 sex= F
height= 6'4" age=27 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
```

POSIX sh solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r column1_in_data column2_in_data column3_in_data rest_of_columns_in_data <&3
  read -r line_in_age; do
  printf '%s\n' "$column1_in_data $column2_in_data $column3_in_data$line_in_age $rest_of_columns_in_data"
done 3<data.txt <age.txt
```

the `<&3` is a redirection so the first read will read from `FD` (file descriptor 3.)

The `${var//search/rep}` is a bash specific P.E. (parameter expansion.)

Awk can do better/faster on large set of files/data I believe.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what this means: "${!data[@]}"

Comment: See: [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30988586/6862601)

Comment: @yoyo31 *If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in name. If name is not an array, expands to 0 if name is set and null otherwise. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.* From [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` and `getline` provides a very simple and efficient solution, e.g.

```
awk '{getline age < "age.txt"; $3=$3 age}1' data.txt
```

Above you are simply using `getline` to read from `age.txt` into the variable `age` and then appending `age` to the 3<sup>rd</sup> field from `data.txt`.

Another way so long as `"age="` only appears once in the line would be:

```
awk '{getline age < "age.txt"; sub(/age=/,"age=" age)}1' data.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can just copy and middle-mouse paste into an xterm in the directory where your files are located, e.g.

```
$ awk '{getline age < "age.txt"; $3=$3 age}1' data.txt
height= 6'1" age=21 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
height= 6'5" age=23 shoe-size=9.0 sex= M
height= 5'11" age=22 shoe-size=8.5 sex= F
height= 5'9" age=19 shoe-size=11.5 sex= M
height= 4'11" age=34 shoe-size=7.5 sex= F
height= 6'4" age=27 shoe-size=9.5 sex= M
```

Comment: what does the '1' at the end do?

Comment: `1` is just shorthand for the default rule `print` `:)`

Comment: Thanks so much David. If I wanted to grab it from a variable instead of a text file, how can I use awk for that? Do I just replace '$3=$3 age' with '$3=$3 $var'?

Comment: You would have to pass `var` in as variable from the shell. You can do that at the beginning with `-v varname="$var"`. However, since `awk` processes all the records, using `getline` to read from the `age.txt` file is probably your best option. (your other option would be to process the `age.txt` file first and just fill an array with the values and then process `data.txt`)

Comment: Let's say I already had a variable that I grab from, how do I place it into awk? Would it be like this? `awk -v '{varname="$var"; $3=$3 varname}1'` data.txt and lastly, how do I save that awk line, would I just have to append it to a new text file or can I use the existing one?

Comment: Yes, I see what you are getting at, but the problem is `awk` is running as a single process. While you can pass a shell variable into `awk`, what is missing is a mechanism for updating a shell variable for each record processed by `awk`. Now I'm not going to say it is "blanket" impossible, but I will say, other than pre-reading all variable values into an array, reading from a file with `getline`, or passing a single shell variable in at the beginning -- I don't know of any way to do what you are wanting to do. (bummer)

Comment: The problem being when you pass `-v varname="$var"` at the beginning, its value is fixed. If you then want to get a new value into `var` for each record processed -- there isn't a way to know when `awk` is done processing each record back in the shell to make the update, and no way for `awk` to update that `var` value from the shell (other than for `awk` doing something with it internally). So where I used `getline` to read a new value into `age` each time I processed a record -- there isn't a counterpart for doing that from a shell variable per-record.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you for that valuable insight David. This helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a bunch of `cut` and `paste` and process substitution:

```sh
paste -d ' ' \
    <(paste -d'\0'  \
        <(cut -d' ' -f-3 data.txt) \
        age.txt) \
    <(cut -d' ' -f4- data.txt)
```

The outer `paste` command uses a blank as the delimiter to paste the output of the inner `paste` and the outer `cut` together.

The inner `paste` uses a null delimiter so there is no blank between `age=` and the age value.

This being said, the input file format seems inconsistent regarding the spacing around `=`.