# How to read cat $1 into a bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, cat

Maybe I'm asking this question wrong, but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. What I'm trying to do is read the lines from a text file passed from the script call (./script.sh textile.txt) and read it into variable. My code is:

```
function read_hosts{
hosts = $(cat "$1")
}

read_hosts $@
```

the script call is:

```
./nexthelper.sh hosts.txt
```

And, hosts.txt contains the following:

```
localhost
www.google.com
```

When I run the code, it throws a syntax error on the `hosts =`  line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net before posting here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash)
`mapfile -t hosts <"$1"`

Comment: KamilCuk, I wasn't aware of that website. Thank you for sharing that!

LéaGris, I'll check out that page and see if that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* After OP confirmed there was no error syntax error around the `=`

Suggesting this syntax since you are used to C++
The function definition lacks the `()` to follow the name

```sh
function read_hosts(){
    # ...
}
```

Other syntaxes

- the `()` can be ommitted if there is a space or new line after the function name

> ```
> function function_name {
> }
> ```

- the `function` keyword is optional if `()` is used

---

In `bash` the syntax for assigning values to variables (or setting variables) is

```
variableName=variableValue
```

Note the lack of space on either side of the `=`.

This is because bash splits everything surrounded by spaces into a command. So when you try `hosts = "something"`, bash is essentially trying to execute a command called hosts, then a command called = and a command called something.

Removing the spaces tells bash that you are trying to assign a value to a variable.

Here are some resources I personally use/d for learning bash:

- https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/bash
- https://devhints.io/bash

Comment: Wait... in my code, it isn't spaced out. I'm more used to coding in C++ so I'll space stuff out without thinking about it. it isn't spaced out, and it still throws an error.

Comment: ah. was focussed on what you had said about the `=` and the spaces that i missed the other syntax error

Comment: added updates. but i'd expect you fixed it by now with [shellcheck.net](//shellcheck.net) 