# How to read a file without knowing its name but knowing its extension using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, readfile

I am trying to change my code to read a .txt file from a directory. That directory contains only one .txt file but I do not know its name beforehand. I only know it is a .txt file. Is it possible to do that using shell script?

Below is my current code to read a file but I have to manually specify the file name.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a var

filename='file.txt'
let count=0

while read line; do
    var[$count]=$line
    ((count++))
done < $filename
```

Comment: Is there a good guide page on how to find existing articles if you don't know what keys to search for? The term `glob` is pretty central to this question, but OP apparently didn't know to use it. What's our best way to help? Using our experience to explain and post links in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that there is only one matching file just replace:

```
done < $filename
```

by:

```
done < *.txt
```

Of course this will fail if you have zero or more than one matching file. So, it would be better to test first. For instance with:

```
tmp=$(shopt -p nullglob || true)
shopt -s nullglob
declare -a filename=(*.txt)
if (( ${#filename[@]} != 1 )); then
  printf 'error: zero or more than one *.txt file\n'
else
  declare -a var
  let count=0
  while read line; do
    var[$count]=$line
    ((count++))
  done < "${filename[0]}"
fi
eval "$tmp"
```

The `shopt` stuff stores the current status of the `nullglob` option in variable `tmp`, enables the option, and restores the initial status at the end. Enabling `nullglob` is needed here if there is a risk that you have zero `*.txt` file. Without `nullglob` that would store literal string `*.txt` in array `filename`.

Your loop could be optimized a bit:

```
  declare -a var
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    var+=("$line")
  done < "${filename[0]}"
```

`IFS=` is needed to preserve leading and trailing spaces in the read lines. Remove it if this is not what you want. The `-r` option of `read` preserves backslashes in the read line. Remove it if this is not what you want. The `+=` assignment automatically adds an element at the end of an indexed array. No need to count. If you want to know how many elements you array contains just use `${#var[@]}` as we did to test the length of the `filename` array.

Note that storing the content of a text file in a bash array is better done with `mapfile` if your bash version is recent enough. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash), for instance.

Comment: I'm wondering if it were not better to store the file name in a normal var and then check if it's a readable file. `filename=*.txt; if [[ -r "$filename" ]]; then...` Or similar.

Comment: `filename=*.txt` assigns the string `*.txt` to variable `filename`. From `bash` manual: "_A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form `name=[value]`...Pathname expansion is not  performed._"

Comment: True. Maybe `filename=$(echo *.txt)` instead. The checking for the file part was what I thought is important. `[[ -r $filename ]]`, or any of the file checking variants that is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter expansion can be triggered in assignments as well!

```
filename=$(echo -n *.txt)
```

If you want to make it foolproof (catching the case that the number of matching files is not 1), assign to an array and check its size:

```
farr=( *.txt )
if (( ${#farr[*]} != 1 ))
then
  echo You lied to may when you said that there is exactly on .txt file
else
  filename=${farr[0]}
fi
```

Comment: _Parameter expansion works in assignments as well!_: does not work here. `touch foo.txt; f=*.txt; echo "$f"` prints `*.txt`. But of course, if you `echo $f` (no quotes) the value of variable `f` undergoes pathname expansion, producing the expected `foo.txt`.

Comment: Good point! I will update my anser accordingly.