# How to reuse an ANSI-C quoting variable in another Bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I'm trying to figure out how to use a variable containing an ANSI-C quoting string as an argument for a subsequent bash command.
The string in the variable itself is a list of files (can virtually be a list of anything).

For example, I have a file containing a list of other files, for example `test.lst` containing :

```
  >$ cat test.lst
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

I need to pass the file content as a single string so I'm doing :
`test_str=$(cat test.lst)`
then converts to ANSI-C quoting string:
`test_str=${test_str@Q}`

So at the end I have :

```
  >$ test_str=$(cat test.lst)
  >$ test_str=${test_str@Q}
  >$ echo $test_str
$'a.txt\nb.txt\nc.txt'
```

which is what I'm looking for.

Then problem arises when I try to reuse this variable as a string list in another bash command.
For example direct use into a for loop :

```
  >$ for str in $test_str; do echo $str; done
$'a.txt\nb.txt\nc.txt'
```

What I expect at this step is that it prints the same thing as the content of the original `test.lst`

I also tried expanding it back but it leaves leading `$'` and trailing `'`

```
  >$ str=${test_str@E}
  >$ echo $str
$'a.txt b.txt c.txt'
```

I also tried `printf` and some other stuffs to no avail. What is the correct way to use such ANSI-C quoting variable into a bash command ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash  --  might prove instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
eval echo "${test_str}"
```

I believe that an ANSI-C quoted string is meant to be `eval`uated by `bash` command line parser.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, why do you need quoting? Just keep the data untouched stored as elements of an array:

```
mapfile -t filelist < test.lst
# iterate through the list
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' "$file"; done
```