# check existence of files from a list in a text file (Linux)?

Tags: linux, bash

Using UNIX/Linux, a simple solution would be:

```
for i in $(< mylist.txt ); do
  if [ ! -r $i ] ; then
    echo "file missing!  $i"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

However this breaks if only one file is specified per line, but the file name may contain spaces. Spaces in file names are popular among users but not programmers, for a reason.
I tried adding quotation marks, but this does not work: in the for command a space is taken as delimiter.

How can I solve this in an easy way?

Comment: Check your scripts with shellcheck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an array from a text file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash)

Comment: See [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/) as well.

Comment: More solutions and alternatives [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 7):

The `for` loop always splits input on whitespace.

We could change the input separator `IFS` to use only newline as separator:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
    IFS='
'
    for i in $(cat mylist.txt)
    do
        if [ ! -r "$i" ]
        then
            echo "file missing!  $i" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    done
)
```

A simpler [and better](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) alternative is to use `read` in a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r i
do
    if [ ! -r "$i" ]
    then
        echo "file missing!  $i" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done <mylist.txt
```

Notice also that we need to quote the expansion of `$i` in the `[` command, and the error message should go to the error stream.

Also, this uses only portable constructs; no need to restrict this to only Bash.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution, the "read" command reads one line at a time:

```
cat mylist.txt | while read i; do
  if [ ! -r "$i" ] ; then
    echo "file missing!  $i"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: No - `while IFS= read -r i; do ...; done < myList.txt`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: See also the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This won't work as expected (i.e. as in the question). The `while` part is executed in a sub-shell and the `exit` will only exit that sub-shell, not the whole script.